# Systematically filling in variable columns

Tags: r, loops, filter, dplyr

I need code to systematically label and fill in variables.

For example, current dataset looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Time = c(1:30), 
                   Value = c(1:30)*2.3)
Time Value
1    2.3
2    4.6
3    6.9
4    9.2
5   11.5
6   13.8
7   16.1
8   18.4
9   20.7
10  23.0
11  25.3
12  27.6
13  29.9
14  32.2
15  34.5
16  36.8
17  39.1
18  41.4
19  43.7
20  46.0
21  48.3
22  50.6
23  52.9
24  55.2
25  57.5
26  59.8
27  62.1
28  64.4
29  66.7
30  69.0
```

I want to create two new variables `Condition` and `Trial`. There are 3 levels in the Condition variable (1~3) and 2 levels in the Trial variable (A or B). Condition level changes every 5 seconds in a specific pattern (1, 3, 2), and the Trial level alternates (A/B) for the first 4 seconds and disappears on the 5th second. Like this:

```
Time  Condition Trial Value
1          1     A   2.3
2          1     B   4.6
3          1     A   6.9
4          1     B   9.2
5          1  <NA>  11.5
6          3     A  13.8
7          3     B  16.1
8          3     A  18.4
9          3     B  20.7
10         3  <NA>  23.0
11         2     A  25.3
12         2     B  27.6
13         2     A  29.9
14         2     B  32.2
15         2  <NA>  34.5
16         1     A  36.8
17         1     B  39.1
18         1     A  41.4
19         1     B  43.7
20         1  <NA>  46.0
21         3     A  48.3
22         3     B  50.6
23         3     A  52.9
24         3     B  55.2
25         3  <NA>  57.5
26         2     A  59.8
27         2     B  62.1
28         2     A  64.4
29         2     B  66.7
30         2  <NA>  69.0
```

How can I accomplish this by relying on `Time`? The code I'm imagining looks something like this:

```
for(every 5 seconds in Time){
     data$Condition <- label as 1, 2, or 3
     data$Trial <- label A or B in an alternating manner, skipping out on the last second}
```

#EDIT: I should specify that my actual dataset differs from the example I provide above. In reality, I am working with a massive dataset, with varying number of rows for a given time range. I need code that will use a specific  range (e.g. every 70 seconds) in `Time` to fill the `Condition` and `Trial` values. For example, `Condition` has 6 levels, which will change every 70 seconds based on a given pattern (let's say, 1, 6, 4, 5, 2, 3). For instance, the Condition variable is labelled as 1 when Time = 0~40 seconds, 6 when Time = 40~80, 4 (80~120), 5 (120~160), 2(160~200), 3(200~240)1 (240~280), and so on until the end of the dataset. For each level in the Condition variable, the Trial variable alternates as A or B every 5 seconds (always starting from A). For example, for Condition 1 (Time = 0~40), Trial is labelled as A when Time = 0~5, B when Time = 5~10, A (10~15),..., B (35~40)..

Snippet of actual dataset:

```
data <- structure(list(Time = c(1.71, 3.2, 4.73, 5.65, 6.65, 
6.75, 7.98, 8.29, 11.39, 13.31, 13.61, 14.28, 16.61, 19.39, 21.57, 
22.77, 23.87, 24.05, 24.32, 24.68, 24.72, 24.79, 25.98, 26.43, 
27.37, 27.67, 28.04, 29.27, 31.29, 31.42, 32.05, 33.45, 33.56, 
34.11, 35.25, 35.84, 37.72, 38.09, 38.59, 39.03, 40.19, 40.64, 
41.44, 42.78, 42.81, 43.15, 43.58, 44.43, 44.69, 44.9, 45.16, 
45.63, 46.86, 48.91, 50.96, 52.03, 52.46, 53.13, 54.28, 55.51, 
55.91, 57.36, 58, 58.17, 58.2, 58.53, 59.3, 59.83, 61.22, 61.75, 
62.28, 63.58, 63.91, 65.04, 66.54, 67.1, 69.45, 71.67, 71.81, 
74.04, 77.19, 78.04, 78.47, 80, 80.11, 81.36, 81.89, 83.09, 83.63, 
83.66, 83.69, 84.26, 84.85, 85.71, 89.29, 90.23, 91.51, 91.78, 
91.95, 96.3, 98.61, 99.08, 99.95, 101.14, 101.44, 102.5, 102.77, 
103.57, 103.8, 105.15, 105.28, 105.48, 105.72, 107.38, 107.77, 
107.93, 108.97, 109.13, 109.23, 109.6, 111.29, 113.12, 113.15, 
113.18, 116.17, 116.37, 117.75, 120.44, 120.91, 121, 122.54, 
123.17, 123.99, 124.39, 125.49, 127.71, 129.11, 130.4, 130.93, 
132.16, 132.73, 133.04, 133.57, 134.15, 134.45, 136.46, 137.43, 
138.43, 139.43, 140.25, 140.61, 143.3, 143.5, 143.56, 145.57, 
146.65, 147.49, 147.61, 147.85, 148.02, 148.8, 151.07, 151.62, 
151.75, 152.16, 153.79, 154.94, 155.04, 155.2, 156.64, 156.7, 
156.77, 157.07, 158.95, 159.15, 160.36, 161.4, 162.07, 162.24, 
162.44, 162.48, 162.67, 162.81, 163.07, 164.89, 165.39, 165.82, 
166.09, 166.72, 166.83, 167.27, 168.61, 170.14, 171.52, 172.26, 
173.13, 173.73, 174.04, 174.18, 174.21, 174.48, 175.21, 175.31, 
175.48, 176.98, 177.56, 178.93, 179.03, 182.21, 184.03, 184.76, 
185.06, 185.77, 186.39, 186.6, 186.95, 187.02, 187.58, 187.91, 
188.08, 189.15, 189.88, 190.47, 191, 191.8, 193.5, 194.69, 195.29, 
195.59, 197.07, 199.4, 200.35, 201.75, 202.28, 202.36, 202.92, 
203.45, 203.62, 204.14, 204.57, 204.78, 204.87, 205.84, 206.47, 
206.58, 207, 208.66, 208.99, 209.22, 212.51, 215.13, 216.02, 
218.51, 218.61, 220.01, 220.04, 220.38, 221.53, 221.96, 222.63, 
223.03, 223.17, 224.28, 225.64, 226.34, 226.38, 226.78, 226.81, 
227.7, 227.76, 227.87, 228.2, 229.73, 230.36, 231.15, 231.58, 
234.83, 235.66, 236.2, 236.46, 237.58, 237.85, 237.88, 238.32, 
238.42, 239.21, 239.38, 240.05, 243.24, 243.87, 243.93, 245.45, 
245.56, 245.75, 247.03, 247.12, 249.97, 250.78, 251.89, 253.99, 
254.57, 257.68, 258.69, 258.85, 259.52, 259.99, 262.81, 263.28, 
263.98, 265.93, 266.06, 268.1, 268.34, 270.18, 274.3, 276.99, 
278.77, 279.54, 279.87, 280.43, 282.29, 282.35, 283.15, 283.35, 
284.59, 285.2, 285.37, 290.75, 290.89, 291.12, 291.29, 293.53, 
294.61, 296.86, 298.64, 299.64, 301.24, 303.29, 307.01, 307.18, 
307.95, 309.66, 309.83, 309.86, 310.13, 310.69, 310.73, 312.01, 
315.36, 316.1, 316.27, 316.56, 316.93, 317, 317.27, 317.9, 318.1, 
319.25, 319.72, 319.99, 320.22, 322.3, 324.96, 326.42, 326.76, 
327.62, 328.35, 328.47, 328.84, 329.27, 329.57, 330.43, 331, 
332.22, 332.75, 334.05, 334.72, 334.86, 335.74, 338.75, 340.86, 
341.84, 341.94, 343.14, 344.61, 344.71, 344.81, 345.85, 349.48, 
349.68, 349.85, 350.61, 353.46, 353.53, 353.76, 354.36, 357.58, 
360.8, 362.11, 362.15, 362.21, 362.35, 362.68, 364.18, 368.26, 
369.02, 369.12, 369.35, 369.49, 369.85, 370.51, 371.68, 371.98, 
372.01, 372.17, 372.47, 374.17, 376.28, 376.75, 377.32, 378.66, 
379.37, 380.97, 381.3, 381.44, 381.54, 381.64, 381.87, 382.79, 
383.13, 385.09, 385.59, 386.74, 387.68, 387.71, 390.29, 390.82, 
391.23, 393.14, 393.21, 393.81, 395.08, 395.11, 395.21, 395.66, 
395.83, 396.16, 396.29, 397.06, 397.23, 398.19, 398.66, 398.83, 
402.77, 404.23, 404.36, 404.64, 405.03, 405.23, 405.27, 405.53, 
406.41, 406.71, 407.18, 408.02, 408.08, 408.65, 409.66, 411.26, 
411.54, 411.76, 412.3, 412.67, 412.95, 413.18, 413.21, 414.51, 
415.09, 415.15, 415.22, 418.1, 418.64, 420.86, 421.55, 423.28, 
424.08, 426.49, 427.42, 429.29, 429.54, 429.68, 429.94, 430.27, 
430.47, 430.91, 431.64, 431.87, 432.34, 434.29, 434.66, 434.9, 
436.21, 438.01, 438.75, 439.08, 439.08, 439.46, 442.56, 443.68, 
444.11, 445, 445.5, 446.36, 446.56, 447.33, 447.36, 448.41, 449.25, 
450.42, 451.2, 452.54, 454.25, 455.62, 455.75, 456.65, 457.43, 
458.5, 460.54, 460.95, 461.02, 461.82, 463.32, 463.48, 464.31, 
465.17, 466.99, 467.12, 467.59, 469.69, 470.64, 472.1, 473.49, 
474.43, 475.16, 477.78, 478.28, 479.61, 480.56, 482.83, 483.89, 
483.96, 484.86, 485.51, 486.76, 487.03, 487.09, 488.8, 489.23, 
489.39, 489.64, 489.68, 489.94, 491.24, 491.31, 491.52, 492.65, 
493.77, 494.77, 494.99, 495.63, 498.45, 500.6, 501.13, 503.42, 
505.42, 505.78, 507.94, 510.02, 511.79, 516.21, 517.26, 517.46, 
519.65, 520.98, 522.11, 523.23, 524.46, 526.09, 526.65, 528.64, 
528.84, 529.08, 529.25, 529.83, 531.6, 532.39, 533.61, 534.71, 
535.25, 535.68, 536.15, 537.53, 537.63, 539.8, 541.28, 542.29, 
542.45, 543.12, 543.8, 544.34, 545.3, 545.64, 548.22, 548.28, 
548.42, 549.06, 549.19, 549.78, 551.61, 552.97, 554.3, 554.71, 
557.79, 558.05, 558.16, 560.54, 562.19, 563.56, 563.59, 563.65, 
563.82, 564.09, 564.49, 565.68, 567.24, 567.48, 567.65, 567.68, 
568.86, 568.92, 570.23, 571.31, 572.26, 572.76, 573.16, 574.09, 
577.21, 579.71, 583.7, 584.1, 585.82, 585.88, 585.95, 586.45, 
586.51, 586.65, 588.26, 588.42, 588.64, 588.87, 589.3, 589.47, 
589.8, 590.84, 591.27, 591.54, 591.6, 592.52, 594.19, 594.65, 
594.82, 595.12, 595.32, 595.64, 596.37, 596.5, 596.57, 596.67, 
596.94, 596.97, 597.33, 597.44, 597.97, 598.44, 598.91, 598.96, 
600.52, 602.71, 603.18, 603.57, 604.74, 607.12, 607.46, 608.12, 
608.26, 608.76, 610.54, 611.08, 611.41, 612.2, 612.73, 615.19, 
616.61, 617.68, 617.81, 619.2, 619.67, 620.97, 621.13, 621.63, 
622.48, 623.01, 623.15, 624.15, 624.21, 624.55, 625.62, 626.07, 
629.98, 630.65, 630.92, 632.57, 632.6, 633.5, 634, 634.77, 635.5, 
635.86, 636.12, 638.79, 639.07, 639.41, 640.37, 642.58, 643.79, 
644.72, 644.76, 645.05, 645.83, 645.85, 647.01, 647.37, 650.86, 
651.09, 651.95, 655.01, 655.61, 656.36, 657.86, 658.83, 660.41, 
660.61, 660.85, 662.35, 662.55, 662.64, 663.3, 664.56, 665.1, 
665.49, 665.99, 666.13, 667.61, 667.75, 667.88, 667.95, 669.15, 
670, 670.37, 670.67, 670.7, 670.9, 671.33, 671.54, 674.18, 677.27, 
677.37, 678, 678.44, 679.14, 679.37, 679.69, 680.28, 681.38, 
682.69, 682.95, 683.41, 685.67, 685.91, 685.97, 687.02, 687.39, 
688.19, 688.29, 690.54, 690.68, 691.31, 692.14, 693.01, 693.24, 
695.12, 696.23, 698.51, 699.98, 700.93, 701.23, 703.94, 707.06, 
711.78, 712.9, 713, 713.13, 715.54, 718.03, 718.07, 719.39, 719.65, 
720.28, 721.02, 721.39, 722.23, 722.77, 724.3, 726.09, 726.66, 
727.16, 727.39, 729.1, 729.24, 729.57, 730.17, 730.97, 732.52, 
733.93, 734.63, 735.64, 735.67, 735.84, 736.57, 736.91, 736.94, 
737.11, 737.67, 738.89, 740.2, 740.7, 741.16, 742.08, 744.41, 
744.5, 745.06, 745.86, 747.03, 747.85, 748.81, 749.18, 751.33, 
751.63, 753.6, 753.9, 754.03, 754.49, 757.12, 758.67, 758.93, 
761.48, 765.27, 767.94, 768.19, 769.12, 769.55, 769.95, 770.16, 
771.77, 771.8, 772.74, 773.13, 773.5, 774.3, 774.77, 775.29, 
775.96, 776.19, 776.52, 777.35, 777.72, 778.27, 778.61, 779.07, 
780.61, 781.28, 781.36, 782.23, 782.7, 783.53, 785.04, 787.58, 
788.92, 789.3, 789.8, 790.26, 790.86, 790.99, 791.5, 792.44, 
793.78, 793.88, 794.68, 794.85, 795.16, 795.19, 795.96, 796.83, 
799.01, 799.05, 799.32, 800.62, 801.48, 803.53, 803.84, 804.17, 
806.18, 806.72, 807.06, 807.45, 808.02, 808.64, 809.64, 811.44, 
812.28, 813.95, 815.67, 816.1, 818.24, 818.69, 819.42, 819.55, 
819.66, 819.82, 821.63, 821.79, 821.87, 822.34, 824.87, 825.07, 
825.39, 825.53, 825.96, 827.79, 827.92, 828.26, 828.41, 829.34, 
829.64, 832.06, 832.83, 833.06, 833.53, 834.56, 836.91, 837.18, 
837.54, 837.65, 839.1, 841.33, 841.4, 842.21, 842.38, 842.58, 
842.82, 843.98, 844.52, 844.82, 845.17, 845.6, 846.8, 847.43, 
849.78, 849.81, 850.18, 850.95, 851.48, 851.8, 852.37, 852.67, 
852.87, 853.84, 855.19, 856.55, 858.05, 858.54, 859.5, 860.57, 
860.88, 860.9, 862.19, 862.42, 862.85, 862.96, 863.69), Value = c(35.54, 
28.32, 28.39, 27.83, 29.44, 29.94, 30.98, 32.92, 28.17, 29.62, 
28.92, 29.91, 29.6, 31.72, 30.77, 30.67, 31.31, 31.04, 30.56, 
31.2, 31.12, 31.12, 29.61, 31.43, 32.09, 32.29, 33.03, 34.83, 
31.1, 31.73, 32.01, 32.98, 33.12, 32.38, 32.21, 32.92, 29.35, 
31.12, 32, 32.08, 32.71, 33.73, 38.35, 38.42, 38.4, 38.77, 36.68, 
38.61, 39.67, 40.4, 40.72, 40.54, 41.92, 40.41, 41.51, 39.74, 
40.22, 42.03, 41.79, 42.13, 41.32, 41.98, 41.4, 41.01, 40.98, 
41.09, 42.13, 41.88, 41.63, 42.42, 43.31, 42.09, 43.61, 44.24, 
43.87, 45.36, 48.3, 48.66, 48.78, 32.48, 26.62, 26.02, 26.37, 
27.24, 27.56, 29.06, 30.21, 30.16, 28.09, 27.32, 27.04, 27.08, 
26.47, 26.18, 30.75, 28.65, 30.16, 30.37, 29.66, 25.69, 25.16, 
24.91, 23.46, 25.76, 25.75, 24.21, 24.12, 25.98, 23.75, 22.23, 
21.9, 21.85, 21.73, 24.61, 25.73, 25.84, 24.59, 24.3, 24.05, 
24.69, 24.8, 27.17, 27.28, 27.26, 39.1, 39.76, 43.77, 45.35, 
46.13, 46.03, 44.84, 45.13, 43.99, 43.5, 44.26, 44.79, 44.48, 
44.77, 45.11, 45.24, 44.35, 43.7, 43.59, 44.54, 44.74, 44.18, 
44.05, 41.75, 43.9, 45.22, 45.35, 45.45, 45.87, 45.79, 46.85, 
48.39, 33.07, 32.45, 30.5, 29.41, 28.08, 24.81, 25.36, 25.41, 
23.61, 24.48, 23.75, 23.38, 23.06, 25.85, 25.67, 25.35, 25.89, 
27.49, 27.25, 26.85, 28.95, 22.96, 22.77, 22.67, 22.68, 23.35, 
24.06, 25.23, 27.63, 28.12, 28.22, 28.37, 29.96, 30.35, 31.43, 
32.05, 31.5, 32.77, 26.65, 27.91, 28.39, 28.17, 28.34, 28.25, 
28.82, 29.06, 28.61, 28.99, 28, 28.6, 29.8, 29.87, 23.96, 23.85, 
24.31, 24.14, 24.02, 23.79, 23.79, 24.23, 24.68, 28.65, 30.15, 
31.06, 32.87, 34.21, 34.12, 34.12, 37.13, 39.15, 37.07, 37.99, 
39.24, 42.75, 46.47, 45.9, 47.55, 47.35, 47.61, 46.34, 47.44, 
47.19, 46.81, 47.15, 47.15, 47.4, 46.31, 46.6, 46.47, 46.42, 
43.86, 45.1, 45.54, 43.95, 44.76, 45.27, 44.42, 44.58, 38.01, 
36.84, 29.47, 27.04, 26.71, 24.72, 24.66, 24.64, 24.26, 23.69, 
27.18, 27.15, 27.61, 27.75, 26.89, 26.77, 26.2, 25.65, 27.26, 
21.86, 21.36, 21.32, 26.9, 28.57, 29.82, 30.53, 28.63, 27.27, 
27.44, 27.06, 27.07, 30.38, 30.53, 25.36, 24.64, 23.12, 23.22, 
26.04, 26.4, 27.51, 28.19, 28.05, 25.01, 18.68, 20.67, 23.42, 
22.53, 28.56, 26.07, 26.04, 28.38, 26.85, 33.58, 34.9, 35.27, 
33.2, 33.18, 32.88, 33.01, 35.34, 31.81, 32.89, 36.26, 36.04, 
35.57, 35.25, 35.16, 35.33, 36.51, 36.82, 37.76, 37.67, 37.69, 
42.1, 42.17, 42.04, 41.33, 30.25, 26.01, 27.93, 25.78, 28.27, 
29.22, 28.64, 23.71, 23.46, 24.2, 23.42, 23.89, 23.88, 23.34, 
22.91, 23.11, 24.58, 24.98, 24.25, 24.39, 24.03, 24.14, 24.14, 
24.15, 24.69, 25.31, 23.35, 22.55, 22.71, 23.07, 24.62, 24.22, 
23.7, 23.17, 23.39, 23.52, 23.05, 20.54, 20.37, 20.49, 20.62, 
22.82, 24.33, 24.05, 28.24, 29.71, 30.06, 32.57, 35.14, 36.04, 
35.25, 35.41, 38.18, 36.75, 36.65, 36.58, 39.1, 40.92, 41.23, 
41.48, 38.61, 40.14, 40.14, 39.76, 40.31, 42.69, 41.24, 40.99, 
40.87, 40.79, 40.38, 40.46, 42.82, 29.03, 30.32, 30.05, 29.86, 
29.55, 29.05, 28.02, 28.68, 24.92, 24.77, 24.28, 25.34, 27.04, 
27.84, 27.91, 28.63, 31.68, 30.74, 30.8, 30.34, 30.22, 30.31, 
29.49, 25.3, 26.12, 26.94, 29.79, 29.16, 27.01, 28.54, 28.68, 
28.01, 27.35, 27.63, 27.58, 27.42, 27.31, 23.24, 23.4, 23.32, 
23.82, 23.12, 23.92, 24.14, 24.98, 25.17, 25.86, 25.71, 25.33, 
23.64, 25.76, 25.52, 24.7, 24.15, 24.34, 24.4, 24.87, 25.75, 
26.03, 28.34, 29.46, 29.38, 29.02, 30.2, 31.34, 31.06, 31.65, 
31.66, 32.37, 33.28, 34.38, 34.41, 36.18, 35.25, 35.48, 35.9, 
37.12, 36.49, 35.38, 35.92, 36.32, 36.85, 37.47, 37.9, 37.5, 
37.2, 37.43, 37.64, 37.56, 37.39, 37.5, 36.7, 36.81, 36.05, 40.22, 
39.11, 38.5, 38.97, 39.23, 40.3, 39.91, 39.62, 38.43, 22.1, 21.16, 
21.51, 22.14, 23.15, 25.9, 25.29, 26.81, 26.87, 27.95, 25.05, 
21.3, 21.28, 22.25, 24.42, 26.44, 27.01, 27.83, 26.74, 24.39, 
21.13, 21.75, 21.78, 22.76, 24.01, 24.1, 24.61, 24.62, 25.13, 
25.5, 26.6, 27.37, 23.47, 24.67, 24.28, 23.98, 23.33, 24.57, 
25.34, 22.1, 25.41, 27.3, 30.81, 31.03, 35.26, 36.44, 36.46, 
36.28, 36.68, 36.5, 36.77, 37.05, 37.69, 37.69, 38.26, 37.72, 
38.02, 37.86, 38.6, 40, 40.5, 40.52, 42.02, 40.48, 36.9, 38.67, 
38.12, 41.4, 41.87, 42.19, 39.6, 38.18, 22.66, 23.31, 24.07, 
28.23, 28.73, 26.96, 25.21, 22.78, 23.07, 22.75, 21.77, 21.18, 
21.72, 22.79, 24.25, 25.52, 24.09, 19.38, 20.42, 22.06, 21.88, 
22.13, 21.74, 22.46, 23.42, 23.3, 23.7, 24.06, 25.72, 22.35, 
24.7, 26.49, 25.8, 24.26, 24.49, 24.48, 25.63, 26.05, 25.9, 24.68, 
23.99, 27.54, 26.73, 30.1, 30.17, 30.61, 33.7, 35.43, 39.35, 
39.3, 39.43, 39.56, 40.18, 40.45, 41.19, 41.75, 41.58, 41.42, 
41.63, 40.56, 40.6, 42.25, 41.04, 41.18, 41.56, 38.42, 37.57, 
33.8, 38.25, 39.56, 41.87, 46.15, 46.23, 46.24, 39.31, 38, 35.89, 
31.62, 30.74, 30.11, 30.44, 30.69, 30.64, 29.5, 27.87, 27.79, 
23.97, 23.71, 22.41, 23.02, 24.78, 24.94, 24.52, 25.06, 24.95, 
26.42, 26.09, 25.82, 25.13, 24.64, 24.67, 26.61, 27.55, 28.27, 
28.1, 29.09, 29.14, 30.58, 27.81, 27.76, 29.08, 28.83, 29.98, 
29.8, 29.31, 29.04, 27.59, 30.26, 30.69, 26.8, 21.32, 21.89, 
25.36, 26.36, 26.15, 26.18, 27.75, 27.85, 26.3, 26.31, 21.29, 
21.25, 20.7, 20.64, 21.66, 21.69, 21.06, 21.9, 20.57, 31.85, 
32.71, 33.74, 37.93, 37.99, 37.47, 37.35, 39.15, 41.59, 42.64, 
43.03, 43.12, 43.06, 43.59, 42.12, 36.73, 37.13, 38.57, 38.44, 
38.23, 36.87, 36.71, 33.52, 35.4, 37.74, 38.44, 40.39, 39.12, 
37.85, 35.71, 34.55, 32.94, 19.84, 19.52, 19.18, 20.23, 20.19, 
20.08, 20.68, 21.35, 26.09, 27.68, 29.22, 29.2, 28.82, 28.32, 
27.69, 27.7, 33.02, 21.7, 23.97, 24.85, 25.08, 25.45, 25.98, 
24.65, 25.38, 32.03, 31.75, 31.32, 31.59, 30.15, 28.8, 22.79, 
22.09, 23.24, 25.04, 25.51, 25.98, 27.46, 27.71, 27.69, 27.56, 
26.96, 25.82, 25.3, 20.97, 21.08, 22.18, 22.95, 24.39, 23.71, 
26.47, 30.37, 33.35, 27.92, 32.17, 33.73, 42.17, 46.03, 46.36, 
46.49, 46.53, 46.25, 42.34, 41.32, 41.48, 40.65, 39.84, 39.87, 
37.17, 37.34, 37.63, 37.93, 39.1, 42.72, 42.14, 42.01, 42.44, 
41.78, 41.87, 42.63, 41.21, 41.86, 45.11, 33.58, 35.21, 35.98, 
36.03, 35.03, 33.5, 32.57, 32.49, 31.72, 31.39, 30.1, 29.55, 
29, 28.6, 26.68, 26.82, 26.81, 27.16, 30.05, 30.39, 28.92, 27.95, 
27.66, 27.67, 28.15, 27.51, 28.21, 28.34, 28.78, 27.03, 24.3, 
24.62, 26.67, 26.03, 24.02, 22.97, 25.12, 25.81, 25.61, 25.55, 
26.67, 26.89, 27.75, 29.21, 30.68, 33.93, 36.45, 38.18, 38.85, 
38.85, 36.66, 35.16, 35.77, 37.94, 39.01, 39.28, 41.23, 43.02, 
43.33, 44.4, 43.69, 44.51, 45.45, 43.49, 41.61, 40.32, 40.81, 
40.51, 41.82, 42.14, 42.39, 42.32, 41.96, 41.99, 41.64, 41.71, 
41.63, 41.6, 41.66, 40.55, 40.51, 40.59, 41.31, 43.52, 42.96, 
41.95, 42.12, 41.77, 32.63, 28.05, 29.48, 30.68, 31.49, 30.03, 
30.22, 24.67, 28.49, 27.23, 26.41, 26.52, 29.27, 28.79, 28.65, 
29.42, 29.6, 29.71, 24.26, 24.34, 24.37, 24.6, 24.24, 23.72, 
23.69, 23.89, 24.73, 25.76, 25.77, 26.02, 26.55, 26.5, 26.94, 
22.51, 24.7, 24.11, 24.83, 23.39, 24.2, 23.39, 23.16, 23.37, 
24.85, 23.16, 23.1, 24.34, 24.6, 24.58, 24.56, 26.69, 27.8, 27.91, 
27.22, 26.6, 31.89, 35.08, 38.79, 38.8, 40.26, 40.81, 40.71, 
39.31, 38.55, 38.27, 38.45, 37.41, 38.27, 39.23, 37.43, 36.85, 
35.66, 37.19, 36.85, 36.78, 35.91, 36.03, 36.87, 37.03, 37.28
)), row.names = c(NA, -1000L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am offering a simple and transparent solution. Get the length of time, as 30 in your example. Create a list for Condition with a "rep" function using the length (30) and members of the respective list (3 or 5).

Condition= rep(c(1,3,2), 30/3)

Follow the same idea with Trial,

Trial=rep(c("A", "B", "A", "B", "NA"), 30/5)

Add the columns to the original data set.

data$Condition=Condition
data$Trial=Trial

Comment: I like this solution for my example problem, but unfortunately, my real data set is massive (500,000 + observations), and the only thing I can consistently manipulate is the time range (e.g. for every X seconds, label Condition Y and Trial Z).

Comment: I made some edits to my original post to make myself more clear

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by using %/% and %% operations

```
data <- data.frame(Time = c(1:30), 
                   Value = c(1:30)*2.3)

conditionlabel=c(1,3,2)
triallabel=c('A','B','A','B', NA)

data2 = data %>% 
  mutate(
    condition = conditionlabel[((Time-1) %/% 5 %% 3) + 1],
    trial = triallabel[(Time-1) %% 5 + 1]
  )

> data2
   Time Value condition trial
1     1   2.3         1     A
2     2   4.6         1     B
3     3   6.9         1     A
4     4   9.2         1     B
5     5  11.5         1  <NA>
6     6  13.8         3     A
7     7  16.1         3     B
8     8  18.4         3     A
9     9  20.7         3     B
10   10  23.0         3  <NA>
11   11  25.3         2     A
12   12  27.6         2     B
13   13  29.9         2     A
14   14  32.2         2     B
15   15  34.5         2  <NA>
16   16  36.8         1     A
17   17  39.1         1     B
18   18  41.4         1     A
19   19  43.7         1     B
20   20  46.0         1  <NA>
21   21  48.3         3     A
22   22  50.6         3     B
23   23  52.9         3     A
24   24  55.2         3     B
25   25  57.5         3  <NA>
26   26  59.8         2     A
27   27  62.1         2     B
28   28  64.4         2     A
29   29  66.7         2     B
30   30  69.0         2  <NA>
```

Comment: thank you for an elegant solution to my example problem. I'm to having troubling adapting your solution to my actual dataset though. See the edits I've made in my original post for more info